# Bind parameter to time dimension argument InfluxDB

Tags: http, code-injection, influxdb, influxql

So from the docs and countless examples online, it's clear that you can bind parameters in the `WHERE` clause of a query submitted to an InfluxDB server via HTTP like so:

```sh
curl -G 'http://example.com/query?' \
        --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM mymeasurement WHERE value > $min' \
        --data-urlencode 'db=mydatabase' \
        --data-urlencode 'params={"min":0}
```

which is great, it protects against code injection. But what if I was grouping things? How can I prevent code injection when grouping by time? This:

```sh
curl -G 'http://example.com/query?' \
        --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM mymeasurement GROUP BY time($interval)'
        --data-urlencode 'db=mydatabase'
        --data-urlencode 'params={"interval":"1m"}'
```

doesn't work. It gives me this response:

```
{ "results": [{
    "statement_id": 0,
    "error": "time dimension must have duration argument"
}]}
```

which indicates that the binding didn't work. So... what do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there isn't a way to bind parameters to anything outside of the `WHERE` clause - which is truly unfortunate since they decided to make "retention policies" part of the data hierarchy (???).

Fortunately, though, for this exact case there's an easy workaround since InfluxQL duration literals are an extremely simple and regular grammar. What you can do is either restrict the user's input to a strict set of durations like e.g. `{'1hr', '5m', '1m'}`, or you can validate them against this regular expression:

```
[0-9]+([unµm]?s|m|h|d|w)
```

which should be enough to totally capture all valid inputs, to the exclusion of all else. (that's what I had decided on).